# Do Java Ellipsis Require Heap Allocation?

Tags: java, android

Is there a kind soul out there somewhere who actually knows whether or not Java's ellipsis implementation involves any Heap allocation behind the scene. It seems reasonable to me for the calling method to do the necessaries on the stack and avoid array/heap allocation altogether, but when it comes to Java I've been proven wrong more times than I can count. If anyone actually knows for sure, I would be most grateful for an answer.

Comment: For future reference, it's called varargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it really is creating an array. Now it's possible that in *some* cases the JVM can do clever stuff to notice that the array can never actually "escape", and that it can actually be created on the stack - but that's nothing to do with the varargs syntax, which is *just* syntactic sugar.

In general, you should treat it as any other array creation. So this:

```
public void foo(int... args)
// Code
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
public void foo(int[] args)
// Code
foo(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Comment: Excellent answer Jon, precisely the information I was looking for...thank you ever so much.